# Run Python script from php, save process pid, and don't wait it to finish

Tags: php, python, linux

I have a PHP script that runs a python script with shell_exec('myScript.py'). It works nicely, but I don't want to wait that python script to finish. Also I need to know that process pID so I can stop it if I want. How can I do both things? I know that adding "& $!" in the terminal after "myScript.py" gives me the pID, and that I can kill that process with: "kill -SIGTERM pID", but only from terminal.
Thanks in advance.

In more detail, this is what i want to achieve:
I got a raspberry pi. That raspberry pi can control stuff with python scripts (lights, sockets...).
Also, i got a home webserver installed in that raspberry pi. The objective is having a webpage, and being able to run and stop that python scripts from it.

Comment: Everything in php is synchronous by default. Even using pthreads, I dont think you can query the process to get the child process because once you issue the shell_exec it blocks that thread.

Comment: @LuckyBurger Thanks for your answer, but I think i explained my problem wrong and you didnt understand it. Sorry about that, I have updated the question.
The pID i need to know is the one of the python script, not the one from the webserver. I just want to run and stop python script from a web. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: So basically what you want to do is just send messages from php to a python script? Why not just write a php page in python? There are few libaries that let you do that... Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you gotta put some bash magic into it.

```
 $a = exec('python myScript.py > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
 echo $a;
```

Comment: It works! After some problems because i was use escapeshellcmd it returns me the process id.
That is really magic! :D Thanks

Comment: @david-chan can you tell me the alter code to run if the server is hosted on Windows? the above doesn't seems to work.